# How to retrieve data from master list in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I have 10-12 tables, where my master data is there and I have to load them by using `findAll()` facility of hibernate.

So for all these 10-12 table I would required to write the same kind of method like this

```
public List<XYZType> getAllXYZType() {
    return XYZRepository.findAll();
}
```

So this kind of code will be repeated for 10-12 times for different entities. 
Is there any way so that I can make it generic ?

Comment: If you are returning 10-12 tables data then how come you store that in XYZType?

Comment: Your `XYZRepository` (whatever that may be) should be generic then...

Comment: Make it generic. Don't forget that later when requirements change, your genericness might come in the way!

Comment: What I meant was like this 
public List<XYZType1> getAllXYZType1() {
    return XYZRepository1.findAll();
    }

public List<XYZType2> getAllXYZType2() {
    return XYZRepository2.findAll();
    }

Similarly 10 others methods would be required and I was trying to avoid that somehow

Comment: Are you using spring-data repositories ?

Comment: @jps- yes I am using Spring-JPA

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T> List<T> getAll(final Class<T> type) {
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(type);
  return crit.list();
}
```

in order to use it just pass the desired class to the function and it will return the list.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to make it generic, I think the **[Abstract Factory Pattern](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/29/abstract-factory-pattern-in-java/)** is what you are looking for.

Your code should be like this:

```
 public interface GenericDAO < T, ID extends Serializable > {
    T findById(ID id);
    List < T > findAll();
 }
```

Take a look at **[DAO Factory patterns with Hibernate](http://www.giuseppeurso.eu/en/dao-factory-patterns-with-hibernate/)** for further information.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> List<T> getLst(final Class<T> beanClass) {
    List<T> lst = new ArrayList<T>();
    Session sess = MyUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        Criteria cr= sess.createCriteria(beanClass);
        lst = cr.list();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sess.close();
    }
    return lst;
}
```